# Android automation tests with Espresso - how to prevent dagger graph memory leaks?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso, dagger-2

My whole project is built with usage of Dagger 2.

My test set has grown and I have multiple tests stored in a lot of .java classes. It is because each file has different environment (tests done on different kind of user or with some specific mocks).

When java file with tests is run, then new Dagger graph is created. But at the same time Dagger graph built by previously ran java file does not die. It takes memory of my device and when I reach like 33 graphs during whole test suite run, then I get out of memory error.

Of course I tried to analyse memory. And I can notice that I have for example 17 UserDataStore objects. When I exclude weak references the only class that keeps them alive is InstrumentationRunner which is Espresso class. I have only one TestRunner instance, only one Application instance in test process and [num of java files with tests] * [objects injected by dagger] and all of them are referenced to TestRunner.

Implementation of my runner is:

```
public class MyTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

    @Override
    public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApplication.class.getName(), context);
    }
}
```

Did any of you face that problem? How to deal with that?

Comment: Could you provide one sample of those test / Java files? How does your test setup look?